# How do I position an image over a canvas?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, canvas

I've used z-index to bring the image in front of the canvas, but how do I vertically and horizontally center the image?

```
.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The above (what I would normally do) doesn't seem to work.

Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/Meeshbhoombah/meeshbhoombah.github.io and the website: http://therealrohanm.me in question. I'm trying to place Logo2 (located in the images folder) over the intro-section canvas, and vertically and horizontally center the image on the page.

Comment: Why not just draw the image on the canvas?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek How would I do that?

Comment: You can Google "Draw image on HTML5 Canvas". The method used to do so is: `ctx.drawImage()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix but it is considered a small hack rather than an actual solution

if your image is 500px;

```
 position : relative;
 margin-left: 50%;
 left : -250px;
```

Comment: It seemed to work but you're right, more of a hack as opposed to a solution. Know an actual way to center it or is that not possible?